# DateTime returning with AM/PM

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a SQL Server database (2008R2) running on a Windows 2003 box.  I'm connecting to it using another Win2003 box.

When I select a datetime value from the database, I'm getting it back in this format:

> 11/5/2014 12:07:46 PM

However, when I'm using a different system (Win2008 connecting to a 2008R2 database), I'm getting it back in a more expected format:

> 2014-11-02 10:53:00

In both of these cases, I'm pulling the values through a Microsoft OLE DB driver directly from the database tables. The SELECT statements are not converting these values in any way.  This is being pulled from some C++ code and logged to a file.  When I connect using SSMS, the values are always in a more expected format (no AM/PM).

**My Question:**
Why am I getting two separate formats from the same version of SQL Server?  Is this an OLE DB Driver setting somewhere?

Comment: Most of the Google results in this area involve the "CONVERT" function.  But that is definitely not going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regional settings control the way dates are displayed. Try changing settings there.

Comment: I tried multiple languages on the client machine with no changes.  It turns out it's in the "Customize" settings!  Thanks for the answer, it led me down the right path.

Comment: Actually, I tried setting these values and retesting.  I'm still getting AM/PM and non-24-hour format.

Comment: It must be something in the app. Are you trying the same application on the Win2008 box?

Comment: Yes.  It's the same thing.  However, the SQL Server drivers are different.  The version 6.0.1 driver (on Win2008) is giving me milliseconds and the version 2000 (on Win2003) is giving me AM/PM.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the same SQL Server? Does it keep the same formatting? Is the application running in your windows session or is it running under a different account? Remember that regional settings are per-user.

Comment: I try connecting from the Win2003 box to the SQL Server on the Win2008 box (which is giving me milliseconds on another box) and I still get the AM/PM format.  That's why I think it's driver.  I'll try going the other way to see what happens (Win2008 box connecting to the win2003 server.)  And yes, everything is running under the accounts that I log in with. (Great tip, though!)

Comment: "It must be something in the app" is correct.  I've spent four days hunting this down.  Down one path, we're using one method of formatting. Down another path, we format it differently.  Thanks for the input.  Marking as accepted since the question wasn't really valid. :\